# Import-CSV messing up filenames

Tags: powershell

I simply want to take a list of filenames from a text file and delete them. I have some very simple code but somehow it is going wrong.

```
$files = Import-Csv C:\temp\PS\duplicate3.csv
   foreach ($file in $files) {  
        Remove-Item -LiteralPath $file -WhatIf      
    }
write-host -foregroundcolor blue  "Delete complete"
```

In the csv file are just a list of paths like

```
C:\temp\test.txt
D:\Photos\Camera\IMG_20190523_151236(1).jpg
```

I get the error, for each line

> Remove-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '@{C' does not exist.'

What is happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: So your file is not a csv file at all. Use `Get-Content` instead of `Import-Csv`

Answer (score 2):

If you use `Import-Csv`, the command will assume that the first row is a header row. If there isn't a header in the first row, you need to specify it. Then, if you want to refer to a column later on, you need to specify the correct header. `Import-Csv` is designed to work with a table, so each row is assumed to have multiple properties.

```
$files = Import-Csv C:\temp\PS\duplicate3.csv -Header Path
   foreach ($file in $files) {  
        Remove-Item -LiteralPath $file.Path -WhatIf      
    }
write-host -foregroundcolor blue  "Delete complete"
```

If I'm understanding your file format right, you should probably just use `Get-Content` instead of `Import-Csv`.

```
$files = Get-Content C:\temp\PS\duplicate3.csv
   foreach ($file in $files) {  
        Remove-Item -LiteralPath $file -WhatIf      
    }
write-host -foregroundcolor blue  "Delete complete"
```

Comment: Nicely done; if the file is indeed just a plain-text file with a path on each line, the simpler and faster solution is to use `Remove-Item -LiteralPath (Get-Content C:\temp\PS\duplicate3.csv) -WhatIf`